# How to write an equation that's nested?

Tags: notation

Let's say I have an equation that's nested:

$$
\displaystyle x = f\left(f\left(f\left(f\left(f\left(i, a_4\right), a_3\right), a_2\right), a_1\right), a_0\right)
$$

If I wanted to write this equation where it's nested from $a_k$ to $a_0$ without writing out all the terms, how would I denote it?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possibilities.  One is

$$
x = f(f(\cdots f(f(i, a_k), a_{k-1}), \ldots, a_1), a_0)
$$

and the other is

$$
x = b_0
$$

where

$$
b_j = f(b_{j+1}, a_j) \qquad 0 \leq j < k
$$
$$
b_k = f(i, a_k)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You could write e.g. write  $x = f(\ldots f(f(i,a_k),a_{k-1})\ldots ,a_0)$

or alternatively define $g_n (y) := f(y,a_n)$ and write the equation as $$x = \left(\bigcirc_{n=0}^k g_n\right)(i)$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with this big circle. What is this called?

Comment: The cirle is here used as the composition operator on a function space: For $h := f \circ g$ we get $h(x) = f(g(x)) \forall x$. The big symbols are just used for repeating the given symbol, like $\bigcup \bigcap \oplus$ e.t.c

Comment: I wouldn't use the big circle notation, it's very ambiguous unless your operator is both commutative and associative.

Comment: @McFry Right, that is a crucial point! As long as you have "count", you could still properly define a direction, without needing commutativity.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the audience (if they're coming from a slightly more computer-scientific background), treating as the function `foldl` could perhaps be the clearest. See also [How to write a functional fold in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83013/how-to-write-a-functional-fold-in-mathematics)